# How to configure PHP on Mac for developing

Tags: php, apache

I'm doing the installation for PHP on Mac, following [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_installation_mac.htm) .

I checked my `httpd.conf`, which is a little different from mine for the following items.

1. Load Module php5_module
2. AddModule mod_php5.c AddType
3. application/x-httpd-php .php

What I have is `Load Module php4_module`, I don't have the item 2 and item 3, so I added these to my `httpd.conf` file. But after I restart my apache server with `apachectl restart`, it says that `This webpage is not available`. I checked the console of Chrome and found this `GET http://localhost/info.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

And I also found that:

- If I didn't add item 2 and item 3 to the configuration file, the PHP
  script just shows on browser, seems it's not parsed.
- If I just add itme 3, when I accessed `info.php` from my browser,
  it's downloaded instead of being displayed.

Anyone knows what's going on here? Did I miss any more configuration?

By the way, it will be grateful if you can provide a proper tutorial for beginner to set up the envrionment for learning PHP, just found so many articles online, but no one can work correctly.

Comment: The first item is not correct - check the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852516/yosemite-apache-php-info-page-not-shown/30385444#30385444

Comment: What do you mean? Should I change `php4_module` to `php5_module' manually? It is PHP 5.5 installed in my local.

Comment: You have to use `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`. Notice that there is no space between `Load` and `Module` and also there are two parameters.

Comment: No luck. Still not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help. I found one useful tool to set up PHP environment quickly. It is `XAMPP`, which is really easy to set up the environment. Now I can start learning PHP freely. But, of course, I will study the configuration about all of this after I have a basic knowledge of PHP.

Thanks again for all your kindly help, hope will discuss with you later in the details.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at akrabats tutorials on how to install PHP on a mac. You can find the one for Maverics at http://akrabat.com/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-mavericks/ and there is also one for yosemite.

Alternatively you could use homebrew or phpbrew to install php beneath the one delivered with MacOS as they are updated more frequently.

And there is also a third was by using the PHP-installer provided by liip at http://php-osx.liip.ch

Besides that I'd definitely recomend having a look at VirtualBox and Vagrant as lots of PHP-projects provide a vagrantfile to ensure all developers have identical development-environments. But that's a totaly different story!

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to learn PHP, regardless of the underlying OS, I would recommend that you install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and install Linux so that you can follow any of the many 'LAMP on linux' tutorials e.g. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/486

This will probably be more straightforward to get up and running, and won't pollute your Mac environment to the same degree.

Comment: It's not convenient for me to install Linux right now. Now I'm using Tomcat and just want to setup an environment first. But the PHP script is not parsed, do you know why? I just have `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in my PHP file, but it's shown as it is in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Update: 6/26/2019

There have been a few changes in PHP and Apache since the other answers were written.  Currently php7 has defaults built in.  They are documented in the file php.ini.default.  That file is not read by the PHP engine because the suffix .default hides the file from the PHP engine. If you want to change the PHP configuration then rename php.ini.default to php.ini. found at

> /etc/php.ini.default

Apache just requires 2 things. Open the file

> /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Uncomment the line

```
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

and add the following to http.conf

```
# Set Apache to hand off php files the the PHP processor
<IfModule php7_module>
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I put mine in the Supplemental configuration section near the end of the file.